# Running Activity Not Brought to Front From Widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-activity

I have a home-screen widget that has an icon that starts/so pose to bring the application activity to the front of the stack if its all ready running.

It destroys the activity if its already running and I don't want that -Just bring it back into view from the home-screen when the widget it tapped.

I've tried every possible flag with no prevail: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, and so on....

The app is min API is 13, the developing device is on API 16(Really!). Any Ideas or do I have something wrong?  Thnx!

```
public class AndaeroWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
 . . .//Some stuff . . .

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.home_widget);
    // When we click the widget, we want to open our main activity.
    Intent launchActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    launchActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchActivity, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);;

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, AndaeroWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
. . .
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the MainActivity launchMode to singleInstance in manifest.

android:launchMode="singleInstance"